# Unable to run android app with prebuilt native library

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a library written in c++, and it is pre built by Androi NDK clang++ with Makefile command, like this:

```
libfoo.so:
    $(CXX) -c -Wall -Werror -fpic ${SRC_PATH}foo.cpp
    $(CXX) -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

and the output of lib is libfoo.so
I'm trying to add it to a new Android Application project by CMakeList, as bellow:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
project("myapplication6")
set(library_pre_built_dir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs")
add_library(lib_foo SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties( lib_foo
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${library_pre_built_dir}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libfoo.so)
add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        native-lib.cpp
        load_share_manual.cpp
        )
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        android
        lib_foo
        log)
```

The Project is built successful, and the APK output file includes all eabi target:
[image]

But it reports error bellow when running it

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.testapp.myapplication6, PID: 22331
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/home/minh/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication6/app/src/main/cpp/../jniLibs/x86_64/libfoo.so" not found
```

It seems using the path in my host PC. How to fix this issue ?
How to make the app using libfoo.so in device path ?

****UPDATE*****:

The solution for this issue is:
Adding flag: -Wl,-soname

for build command

```
    $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname=libfoo.so -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

Comment: _"it is pre built by Androi NDK g++"_ GCC was removed from the NDK 5 years ago. Any reason why you're using such an old version? As for the dynamic linking error, you could try adding `-soname libfoo.so` after `-shared` in your makefile and see if that helps.

Comment: @Michael Sorry my mistake, I used clang++.
I tried with -soname option but it reports an error: 
clang++: error: unknown argument: '-soname'

Comment: Thanks @Michael very much, I tried again with the build command: 
$(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname=libfoo.so -o libfoo.so foo.o
And It works nice now.